# Can't bind to 'ng-click' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-click

Here is a simple jquery function in my ts component

```
open_user(user) {
  $(user).css("visibility", "visible");
  $(user).css("opacity", "1");
}
```

Here is how I call it in html

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of arrUsers" ng-click="open_user({{user.id}})">
    <img src={{user.profile_img}} class=user-image>
    ...
</div>
```

I am getting this error

Can't bind to 'ng-click' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of arrUsers" [ERROR ->]ng-click="open_user({{user.id}})">
```

Cannot find a solution anywhere..

P.S. New to angular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ng-click` is for angularjs, your template looks like angular 2+, if so, use `(click)="..."` instead.

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of arrUsers" (click)="open_user(user.id)">
```

Also note that using jquery for DOM manipulation in angular app is generally not a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

use **`(click)`** instead of **`ng-click`** . Also you should not use **`interpolation`** when you are passing the argument.

And Do not access DOM inside the component, instead you should use **[`NgStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)**

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of arrUsers" (click)="open_user(user.id)">
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-Click for AngularJS is deprecated since Angular 2 and you should use this :

```
<div class="user" *ngFor="let user of arrUsers" (click)="open_user(event, user)">
</div>
```

In your class component :

```
open_user(event, user) {
    // do something
}
```

And I hope to fix it